# TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties

Tags: flash, typeerror, flash-cs6

I was trying to program an interactive storybook. after adding the event listener and event handler, I tried to test the project and had this error. I tried my best to do away with this error but couldn't. TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
    at Main()

below is the code.

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    var startPage:StartPage;
    var hillPage:HillPage;
    var pondPage:PondPage;


    public function Main()
    {
        startPage = new StartPage();
        hillPage = new HillPage();
        pondPage = new PondPage();
        addChild(startPage);

        //Add event Listeners
        startPage.hillButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onHillButtonClick);
        startPage.PondButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPondButtonClick);
    }
    //Event Handlers
    function onHillButtonClick(Event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        addChild(hillPage);
        removeChild(startPage);
    }
    function onPondButtonClick(Event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        addChild(pondPage);
        removeChild(startPage);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: it would greatly help us help you if you could provide the code that you're using. All we can tell is that a 'term is undefined' which usually means you haven't declared something.

If you can't provide code then I'd suggest the manual method of introducing a load of incremented trace statements throughout your code to narrow down at which point it's failing.

Comment: Visualife I like to send you the code true email if you don't mind?

Comment: i like to send you the cod true email. please send me your email address.

Comment: sorry, I can't put my email on here.

I'll put some trace suggestions in an answer, try those and maybe you're need to show us your page code.

Answer (score 0):

suggested traces to narrow down the issue, just paste back the debug

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {   trace('Main');
        var startPage:StartPage;        trace(' 0');
        var hillPage:HillPage;          trace(' 1');
        var pondPage:PondPage;          trace(' 2');

        public function Main() {
            trace('# Main');

            startPage = new StartPage();        trace(' a');
            hillPage = new HillPage();          trace(' b');
            pondPage = new PondPage();          trace(' c');
            addChild(startPage);                trace(' d');

            //Add event Listeners
            startPage.hillButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onHillButtonClick);
            startPage.PondButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPondButtonClick);
            trace(' events added');
        }

        //Event Handlers
        function onHillButtonClick(Event:MouseEvent):void {             trace('# onHill clicked');
            addChild(hillPage);             trace(' add');
            removeChild(startPage);         trace(' remove');
        }
        function onPondButtonClick(Event:MouseEvent):void {             trace('# onHill clicked');
            addChild(pondPage);             trace(' add');
            removeChild(startPage);         trace(' remove');
        }
    }
}
```